# UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints breakpoint is hit without console warning

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I am not seeing any console print outs of auto layout warnings but when I set the UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints symbolic break point, it gets hit and I am unable to decipher what's wrong with the auto layout constraints. I have tried printing out the back trace but that doesn't give me any helpful information about which layout is ambiguous. I have also tried the *po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]* command and that prints out the auto layout tree but doesn't tell me which constraints are ambiguous or broken. How else can I understand what's wrong with the auto layout when UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints breakpoint is hit but there is no corresponding console log?